# AngularJS date filter convert shortDate format to 'M/d/yy' as label/string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

Is it possible to convert shortDate format to string? I want to put the format to my label. For example I have a code of `<label>{{dateFormat}}</label>` then the `dateFormat` contains the equivalent format of shortDate. Output will be `M/d/yy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the answer. Angular's service `$locale` will do the work. `$locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.shortDate` will display `M/d/yy`. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Check angularjs [date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date):

```
<label>{{ dateFormat | date : 'M/d/yy'}}</label>
```

And here is demo:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="">
  <span>{{1443088830219 | date:'M/d/yy'}}</span><br>
</body>
```